# How to expand height of the container div whenever child divs are expanded

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

In my HTML page I have a few `<div>`s, which can be expanded on clicking their respective links. My requirement is whenever I click on that link, size of its parent container must be increased to the `<div>`'s size (just like an accordion that expands).

This is what I've tried:

```
$('.add-comment').click(function() {
    $('div.extra').height($('div.extra').height() + $('div.stream-widgets-block-comment-box').height());
});
```

The above statement adds the `<div>`'s height, but the problem is as it is yet not expanded while the code is getting executed, so the `<div>`'s height ends up being -1.

EDIT 1: This is the JSFiddle link - http://jsfiddle.net/R9uEh/1/
I have added single div in it, which on expansion uses the height of the page. (Need to click on Add a comment to check the expansion)

Comment: Can you provide jsfiddle.net example?

Comment: What do you mean by "size of the page"?

Comment: @Nikolay : http://jsfiddle.net/R9uEh/

Comment: @Léo : Size of the page as in Height of the page. or I would better say height of its parent container.

Comment: Could you try isolating the code? Including the whole code makes it hard to test.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.add-comment').click(function() {
    var vHeight = $('div.extra').height() + $('div.stream-widgets-block-comment-box').height();
    $('div.extra').css('height', vHeight);
});
```

You can use .css() and var.

Comment: As I have mentioned above, $('div.stream-widgets-block-comment-box').height() is coming as -1, since the code is getting executed before the div expands. :(

Comment: Use setTimeout or callback function,..etc..  That point is delaying ordered function.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing it like so.

```
$('.add-comment').click(function(){
  var height = $('div.extra').height() + $('div.stream-widgets-block-comment-box').prop('scrollHeight');

  ('div.extra').height( height );
});
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function is the result :|

Comment: There's a syntax error: the fourth line is missing a `$` at the beginning of the line. Additionally, this is basically just the same as the OP's code, so this will definitely not work.

Comment: Try wrapping stream-widgets-block-comment-box in another div and setting overflow hidden on it. That way property scrollHeight will return proper height for stream-widgets-block-comment-box div.